# ionic: cannot access form by name in the controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic app I want to clear (`$setPristine()`) the form in case of error.
but I get `Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined`.

```
    <ion-view view-title="Register Form">
      <ion-content>
        <form ng-submit="signup()" id="regForm" name="regForm" novalidate>
          <div ......etc
             <input type="password" ng-model="user.password_c" valid-password-c required>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

here is the controller:

```
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope ...) {
          $scope.signup = function () {
            AuthService.register(user).then(function (msg) {...})
            }, function (errMsg) {
              $scope.user={};
              $scope.regForm.$setPristine();
            });};
    })
```

I don't know if `ion-content` or `validation directive` is messing with the scope that the form is undefined. the AngularJs version is 1.5 I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same kind of problem. I could find the form in  `$scope.$$childTail` or `$scope.$$childTail.$$childHead.$parent`. Just try to access form using `$scope.$$childTail.regForm` or `$scope.$$childTail.$$childHead.$parent.regForm`. Hope this will help to you.

Comment: great! glad to hear that.